# pandas dataframe indexing filtering

Tags: python, indexing, pandas, filter

I have two dataframes in the same time resolution. From the first dataframe (in my case: df_data1) I only want to have all values ['A'] where ['B'] is < 90. And now I'd like filter my secound dataframe so that I have only the values with the same timestamp(timeindex) from my first dataframe

```
df_data1 = pd.io.parsers.read_csv(station_path, skiprows=0, index_col=0, na_values=[-999], names= names_header , sep=';', header=None , squeeze=True)

date     A  B
16.08.2013 03:00     -1  97
16.08.2013 03:15     -1  95
16.08.2013 03:30     0   92
16.08.2013 03:45     4  90
16.08.2013 04:00     18 88
16.08.2013 04:15     42 86
16.08.2013 04:30 73 83
16.08.2013 04:45     110    81
16.08.2013 05:00    151 78
```

Now I'd like to have all df_data['A'] where df_data['B'] is <90.
So I do:

```
df_data = df_data[(df_data['B']  < 90)]
```

the second dataframe looks like:

```
df_data2 = pd.io.parsers.read_csv(station_path, skiprows=1, sep=";",  index_col=False, header=None)

date    w   x   y   z
16.08.2013 03:00    0   0   0   0
16.08.2013 03:15    0   0   0   0
16.08.2013 03:30    0   0   0   0
16.08.2013 03:45    0   0   0   0
16.08.2013 04:00    0   0   0   0
16.08.2013 04:15    0   0   0   0
16.08.2013 04:30    47  47  48  0
16.08.2013 04:45    77  78  79  88
16.08.2013 05:00    111 112 113 125
```

Have anyone an idea to solve this?
I need the dataframes in the same shape cause furthermore I'd like to calculate the `np.corrcoef` and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well your first part is pretty much done:

```
df_data = df_data[(df_data['B']  < 90)]
```

you can then access column A using `df_data['A']`

if your index values are the same in both df then this should work:

```
In [40]:

df1.loc[df_data.index]
Out[40]:
                       w    x    y   z
date                                  
2013-08-16 04:00:00    0    0    0   0
2013-08-16 04:15:00    0    0    0   0
2013-08-16 04:30:00   47   47   48   0
2013-08-16 04:45:00   77   78   79  88
2013-08-16 05:00:00  111  112  125 NaN
```

**EDIT**

Unclear why you get a `KeyError` but you can use the following also:

```
df_data2[df_data2.index.isin(df_data1.index)]
```

This will handle any index values that are not present in your second df.

Comment: Thx for answering!
I got this error:
File "C:\WinPython-64bit-2.7.9.3\python-2.7.9.amd64\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1283, in _has_valid_type
    (key, self.obj._get_axis_name(axis)))

Comment: Are you using my answer verbatim or doing this: `df_data2.loc[df_data.index]`?

Comment: df_data1 is from Type TimeSeries
and 
df_data2 is from Type DataFrame
is this a problem?

Comment: It should still work, can you post raw input data and code to reproduce your problem, an alternative is `df_data2[df_data2.index.isin(df_data1.index)]`

Answer (score 1):

to complete this:

- with the first approach I got an error

but with the following expression it works well:

df_data2[df_data2.index.isin(df_data1.index)]